# pylintrc file not being detected in LiClipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev, pylint, liclipse

This is the command that is run by LiCLipse

```
PyLint: Executing command line: /usr/local/bin/pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc /Users/yogibear/google-python-exercises/basic/string2.py
```

This is the option I am using to add a pylint configuration file in LiCLipse. I am using the latest version of LiClipse. Relative path.

```
 --rcfile=.pylintrc
```

The contents of the file are

```
[FORMAT]
ident-string='  '
```

Path to the rcfile is:

```
/Users/yogibear/google-python-exercises/basic/.pylintrc
```

It doesn't seem to be detecting the file since it still complains about my python source code file having 2 tabs ?

I have named the pylint configuration file as '.pylintrc'.

absolute path to the file works. Its just when I only specify the filename, it can't find it. Why aren't relative paths working ? What is the project root in eclipse pydev ?

New to pylint so not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

PyLint is always run in the project root, so, for `--rcfile=.pylintrc`, the `.pylintrc` file must be in the project root (right next to `.project` and `.pydevproject`).